# Impersonate a WCF client with a specific windows identity

Tags: wcf, impersonation

Through [custom auth logic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158) I already have an instance of [WindowsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx).
Now I want to call a WCF service and pass the identity:

```
WindowsIdentity id = ... // get from session etc.
using (id.Impersonate())
{
   var proxy = ... // create or access
   proxy.DoSomething();             
}
```

The above code **works fine**. But it has the drawback that you need to wrap every call in an impersonation scope (it's easy to forget, thus error-prone and for an existing app a lot of code needs to be changed).

I have also found an alternative to pass the credential:

```
var client = new SomeClient(new InstanceContext(callback), GetEndpointName());
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(cached.User, cached.Password);
```

This has the advantage that it can be set in a central factory method and minimates the change to the existing code base. My application has the credentials cached and could do this, however since I already have a WindowsIdentity instance I thought it wouldn't be needed. Also am not sure if the performance of option two is slower, since username/pwd needs an additional resolving.

Is option two a good one or are there any drawbacks?
Or is there a third option that allows to pass the WindowsIdentity when creating the WCF proxy?

Comment: For the moment I have chosen to code the id.Impersonate() using wrapper for  each method call. Not perfectly elegant code, but at least that approach is documented by Microsoft